# Error/Unexpected behavior using pipe between two threads in C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to get two threads to communicate through a pipe in C++ on linux (Ubuntu, 12.04, 3.8.13). I just want to write a character from one thread to the pipe, and get the other thread to read it and display it.

I am using the clone() function to create threads. This is related to some homework, so I cannot use pthreads or something else.

The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>

#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int p[2];//pipe

void read_pipe()
{
        int c;
    char charac[2];
        read(p[0],charac,sizeof(charac));
    //usleep(1000);
    cerr<<"Read from pipe: "<<charac<<endl;
}

void write_pipe ()
{      

    write(p[1],"a",sizeof("a"));
    cerr<<"Wrote to pipe: "<<"a"<<endl;
}

int thread1(void*)
{   
    close(p[0]);
    write_pipe();
    _exit(0);   
}

int thread2(void*)
{
    close (p[1]);
    read_pipe();
    _exit(0);   
}


int main()
{
    pipe(p);

    char *stack_thread1=(char*)malloc(16384);
    stack_thread1 +=16383;//stack grows downward -- gives seg fault otherwise

    char *stack_thread2=(char*)malloc(16384);
    stack_thread2 +=16383;//stack grows downward -- gives seg fault otherwise

    int64_t elapsed_ns=0;

    //create thread1
    int tpid1=clone(thread1, (void*)stack_thread1, CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_VM, NULL); 
    cerr<<"\nThread1 created\n";

    //create thread2
    int tpid2=clone(thread2, (void*)stack_thread2, CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_VM, NULL); 
    cerr<<"\nThread2 created\n";                        

    waitpid(tpid1,NULL,__WCLONE);//wait for clones to finish
    waitpid(tpid2,NULL,__WCLONE);
    usleep(5000);//make sure clones finished
    cout<<"\nMain thread after sleep\n";        


    return 0;

}
```

Output is weird, different each time, for example:

```
Thread1 created

Thread2 created
Read from pipe: 

Main thread after sleep
```

Sometimes it gives me the error: Illegal instruction. Running it in gdb also gives me illegal instruction.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First you close the pipes?!! and after that you do read or write...!!!

Comment: Before writing to the pipe, I must close the reading end of the pipe and similarly before reading the pipe, I must close the writing end. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @AzureMinotaur hi. can you please post your edited final code or somehow you can provide it? I need to implement this exact code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the `CLONE_FILES` flag, you can't close your pipe files because both threads share the same set of file descriptors. Closing it from one thread will close it for the other thread as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem. Although it's weird that my actual code, which is almost the same doesn't work (same errors). I am timing the time it takes to communicate through the pipe by placing clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,..) before write and after read to the pipe. Any ideas why that doesn't work?

Comment: With the specified change, the code in the question works. It is rather hard for me to troubleshoot code I can't see. Can you update your question with the failing code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I replied prematurely last time. To correct myself, even in this code I get "illegal instruction" a couple of times (6/10 times?). I tested it on two different ubuntu installations. I just removed the CLONE_FILES from both clone() calls. Does it work fine for you every time?

Comment: It works every time here, but the output is different. `std::cerr` is not thread safe and you have no locking around it. This probably means you're causing undefined behavior. By the way, the change I was suggesting was to remove the `close`, not the `CLONE_FILES`.